# Linux IPC implementation guess

Tags: c++, c, ipc

When i am using a c++ IPC library, it return a warning message "you are using multiple multicast interfaces. ; going to use [eth1][192.168.1.11]". Does it indicate it is using domain socket under the hood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at all - where did you get that idea? "eth1" is the name of a (physical) network interface, and "192.168.1.11" is an IPv4 address, probably one that's bound to that interface. A UNIX domain socket would have a name that looks like a filesystem path.

Comment: ok, so an IPC should has nothing to do with a multicast interface

Comment: Nothing at all. IPC is "inter-process communication". It can take place in any number of ways.